# BizTalk Enterprise Single Sign-On Server installation error

Tags: installation, biztalk

I am having some trouble installing BizTalk Server 2010 on my machine. Downloaded the installer from MSDN but run into the issue of:

*Showing MessageBox with text: The following platform components failed to install and will need to be manually installed before setup can proceed: Enterprise Single Sign-On Server: Unspecified error Check the log for details. Return Code: 1 === Logging stopped: 09:55:15 17 April 2013 ===*

Searching the web hasn't really helped and instead caused a lot of confusion. I have accepted all the defaults when attempting to install but then it complains about needing to install the Enterprise Single Sign-On server manually?

I am using Windows 7.

Anyone else experienced this issue?

Thanks in advance, Onam.

Comment: Did you eventually find a way around this? We are having a similar issue.

Comment: Could you provide the install log part which has more detailed info about the failure of installation?

I have had the same problem with BizTalk 2013 on Windows 8, but never on BT10-W7 combo. 

The solution that worked for me was 'create the SSO Administrators group (windows group), before running the configuration tool'. 

I do not know if this has any relevance to your problem, but the symptoms where the same, so i thought i mention my solution.

Comment: @FMFF sorry didn't find a workaround I eventually got another machine and installed it OK.

Answer (score 2):

While installing BizTalk 2016, I encountered this error when I installed only the x86 version of Microsoft Visual C++ 2013 and **didn't install x64 version on a 64 bit machine**.

Once I installed x64 version as well, the error didn't appear and the installation succeeded.

The error/note that appears in the setup/install wizard when the Enterprise SSO feature is selected, is misleading as it only asks to install the x86 version.

However the install guide that lists pre-requisites for the BizTalk, does mention that both x86 and x64 versions of the Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 (or 2013 in case fo BizTalk 2016) Redistributable Package, should be installed.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj248697(v=bts.80).aspx
http://www.biztalkgurus.com/blogs/msft-biztalk-integration/biztalk-2013-installation-error-on-windows-server-2012-64-bit/

Comment: I had the exact same issue and when I installed the VC++ 2013 Redistributable x64, the installation succeeded. Thanks for this answer.